# NullPointerException after Closing App with Service still running

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, nullpointerexception

When I close my application, the service that had been started is supposed to continue running in the background. For some reason, the application crashes and throws a NullPointerException upon closing it.

I am using a MQTTConstants class to keep all the Constants in one place, and within that class I have a Hashset declared, which  is then modified throughout the life of the application.

**Is it possible that by closing the app, this information is being cleared? Although the service is never disconnected.**

The service would continue to work off of this TOPIC_SET as it continues to run in the background.

```
  public static HashSet<String> TOPIC_SET = new HashSet<String>();
```

**STACK TRACE**

> 02-20 14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753): FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   MQTTservice 02-20 14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753): Process:
>   com.l.ltestmqtt, PID: 14753 02-20 14:14:30.620:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14753): java.lang.NullPointerException 02-20
>   14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):    at
>   com.l.ltestmqtt.MQTTService.handleStartAction(MQTTService.java:315)
>   02-20 14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):  at
>   com.l.ltestmqtt.MQTTService.handleStart(MQTTService.java:231)
>   02-20 14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):  at
>   com.l.ltestmqtt.MQTTService$2.run(MQTTService.java:196)
>   02-20 14:14:30.620: E/AndroidRuntime(14753):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Here are the methods that are named within the Stack Trace

**handleStart**

```
synchronized void handleStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // before we start - check for a couple of reasons why we should stop
    Log.e("SERVICE", "----------HANDLESTART()-----------");

    if (mqttClient == null) {
      // we were unable to define the MQTT client connection, so we stop
      // immediately - there is nothing that we can do
      stopSelf();
      return;
    }

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm.getBackgroundDataSetting() == false) // respect the user's request not to use data!
    {
      // user has disabled background data
      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.NOTCONNECTED_DATADISABLED;

      // update the app to show that the connection has been disabled
      broadcastServiceStatus("Not connected - background data disabled");

      // we have a listener running that will notify us when this
      // preference changes, and will call handleStart again when it
      // is - letting us pick up where we leave off now
      return;
    }
    if (!handleStartAction(intent)) {
      // the Activity UI has started the MQTT service - this may be starting
      // the Service new for the first time, or after the Service has been
      // running for some time (multiple calls to startService don't start
      // multiple Services, but it does call this method multiple times)
      // if we have been running already, we re-send any stored data
      rebroadcastStatus();
      rebroadcastReceivedMessages();
    }

    // if the Service was already running and we're already connected - we
    // don't need to do anything
    if (isAlreadyConnected() == false) {
      // set the status to show we're trying to connect
      connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.CONNECTING;

      // we are creating a background service that will run forever until
      // the user explicity stops it. so - in case they start needing
      // to save battery life - we should ensure that they don't forget
      // we're running, by leaving an ongoing notification in the status
      // bar while we are running
      NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification notification =
          new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "MQTT", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MQTTNotifier.class);
      PendingIntent contentIntent =
          PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "MQTT", "MQTT Service is running", contentIntent);
      nm.notify(MQTTConstants.MQTT_NOTIFICATION_ONGOING, notification);


      // before we attempt to connect - we check if the phone has a
      // working data connection
      if (isOnline()) {
        // we think we have an Internet connection, so try to connect
        // to the message broker
        if (connectToBroker()) {
          // we subscribe to a topic - registering to receive push
          // notifications with a particular key
          // in a 'real' app, you might want to subscribe to multiple
          // topics - I'm just subscribing to one as an example
          // note that this topicName could include a wildcard, so
          // even just with one subscription, we could receive
          // messages for multiple topics


          //subscribe to initial TOPIC_SET topics, ie device_id_topic, all_topic
          subscribeToAllTopics();
          //subscribeToTopic(topicName);
        }
      } else {
        // we can't do anything now because we don't have a working
        // data connection
        connectionStatus = MQTTConnectionStatus.NOTCONNECTED_WAITINGFORINTERNET;

        // inform the app that we are not connected
        broadcastServiceStatus("Waiting for network connection");
      }
    }

    // changes to the phone's network - such as bouncing between WiFi
    // and mobile data networks - can break the MQTT connection
    // the MQTT connectionLost can be a bit slow to notice, so we use
    // Android's inbuilt notification system to be informed of0
    // network changes - so we can reconnect immediately, without
    // having to wait for the MQTT timeout
    if (netConnReceiver == null) {
      netConnReceiver = new NetworkConnectionIntentReceiver();
      registerReceiver(netConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    }

    // creates the intents that are used to wake up the phone when it is
    // time to ping the server
    if (pingSender == null) {
      pingSender = new PingSender();
      registerReceiver(pingSender, new IntentFilter(MQTTConstants.MQTT_PING_ACTION));
    }
  }
```

**handleStartAction**

```
  private boolean handleStartAction(Intent intent) {
String action = intent.getAction();

if (action == null) {
  return false;
}

if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_INTENT)) {
  handleSubscribeTopicIntent(intent);
}

if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_PUBLISH_MSG_INTENT)) {
  handlePublishMessageIntent(intent);
}

if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_UNSUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_INTENT)) {
  handleUnsubscribeTopicIntent(intent);
}

return true;
}
```

**UPDATES:** The problem exists within the handleStart() method. If I comment this `if (!handleStartAction(intent)) {` the issue no longer occurs.

**FOR ρяσѕρєя K**
The service is started inside MQTTNotifier Activity using this

> ```
>     MQTTServiceDelegate.startService(this);
> ```

which references this method inside the MQTTServiceDelegateClass

> 

```
public static void startService(Context context) {
    Intent svc = new Intent(context, MQTTService.class);
    context.startService(svc);
  }
```

Comment: what is line number `315` ?

Comment: String action = intent.getAction();, I have isolated the problem to the handleStartAction() method.

Comment: Means `handleStart` method getting null intent . from where passing intent to `handleStart` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I updated the question with more information.

Comment: So If the Intent is null after I close the application, how can I keep it from becoming null? or what can I do to resolve this type of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I will mark this as the answer unless someone is able to provide a better solution.

I ran a quick test to see if the intent was == null, and if it was I just logged it, otherwise I processed the code.

```
  private boolean handleStartAction(Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null) {
      Log.e("NULL INTENT", "***************NULL INTENT**************");
    } else {
      String action = intent.getAction();

      if (action == null) {
        return false;
      }

      if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_INTENT)) {
        handleSubscribeTopicIntent(intent);
      }

      if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_PUBLISH_MSG_INTENT)) {
        handlePublishMessageIntent(intent);
      }

      if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(MQTTConstants.MQTT_UNSUBSCRIBE_TOPIC_INTENT)) {
        handleUnsubscribeTopicIntent(intent);
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```